# How to remove decimal points in Eval in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression, decimal, eval

My code is :

```
      <%# Eval("height")+"cm"%>
```

Output :

```
   170.00cm
```

But I want output : 170cm

Help please.

Comment: You might want to check out [Standard Numeric Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your decimal value to int. So zero's will be truncated.
Check below code:

```
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("height"))+"cm"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

decimal time1 = Convert.ToDecimal(time);

time1 = Math.Round(time1, 0);